Bootstrap not loading properly
I download bootstrap and linked the css and js bundle files yet bootstrap components are not loading properly.
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="dropdown">
        <button class="btn btn-secondary dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropdownMenuButton" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
          Dropdown button
        </button>
        <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuButton">
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    <script src="js/bootstrap.bundle.js"></script>
</body>
</html>

js is not working in dropdownenter image description here menus etc. the components look weird too. Is there something wrong I am doing?

Your screenshot looks all good to me, the button is shown as a dropdown. What exactly is your problem? What does 'components look weird' mean, can you show a screenshot about that as well?

You have not included your bootstap version. If you are using Bootstrap 5, add data-bs-toggle="dropdown" to you button element - that might be a reason why it does not work --> see here: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/components/dropdowns/

Thank you as I said to the other answer I realized I used 4.0 docs. appreciate the help



<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-QWTKZyjpPEjISv5WaRU9OFeRpok6YctnYmDr5pNlyT2bRjXh0JMhjY6hW+ALEwIH" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="dropdown">
    <button class="btn btn-secondary dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropdownMenuButton" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
          Dropdown button
        </button>
    <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuButton">
      <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
      <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
      <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-YvpcrYf0tY3lHB60NNkmXc5s9fDVZLESaAA55NDzOxhy9GkcIdslK1eN7N6jIeHz" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>

</html>



In Bootstrap 5 components like dropdowns rely on data attributes or JavaScript for initialization. For dropdowns the proper data attribute is data-bs-toggle="dropdown".

Thank you I realized I used the 4.0 docs for the dropdown component but I was using the latest version. appreciate the help.
